# Line number for two columns in "ctexbook" on the outer margins fails

Tags: two-column, line-numbering, ctex

As need to compile Chinese characters, I use the `ctexbook` style. When adding line numbers for two columns on the outer margins with `\usepackage[switch]{lineno}`, I see there are not on the outer margins.

```
 \documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.6cm} 
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Outputs:

[image]

How should I move the line numbers on the center to the left?